# WSO2 6.6.0 Analytics - How to change to MySQL

Tags: mysql, wso2, analytics, dashboard

My environment : Centos 7.9 server , installed via rpm : wso2ei-linux-installer-x64-6.6.0.rpm
I have changed the Carbon database to MySQL follow this intruction : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Changing+to+MySQL and it works fine.

Now I want to change Analytics Dashboard and Worker to MySQL too.

I have updated jdbcUrl, driverClassName, username, password in /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml for WSO2_DASHBOARD_DB , BUSINESS_RULES_DB , WSO2_STATUS_DASHBOARD_DB , WSO2_METRICS_DB , WSO2_PERMISSIONS_DB , EI_ANALYTICS databases . I created these databases in MySQL already and granted permission .

When I try to access https://10.3.14.4:9643/portal/ I get error "Problem accessing: /portal/. Reason: Not Found"

I guess that Analytics Dashboard and Worker didn't create tables for dbs when services starting but I cannot find dbscripts for initializing these dbs .

I can only find

/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/wso2/dashboard/dbscripts/metrics/mysql.sql

/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/wso2/worker/dbscripts/metrics/mysql.sql

And I'm not sure what is it for.

Please give me some advice thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding java mysql driver into /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/lib , now I can access https://10.3.14.4:9643/portal/